# I am trying to retrieve the a href attribute and text value in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The following code in JAVA is helping to get my answer:

```
 Elements aElement = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
    for (Element e:aElement) {
        if(e.attr("href").contains("director/")) {
            companyInfo.setName(e.text().trim());
            break;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to retrieve the Director name from the following link:
https://www.zaubacorp.com/company/SHRI-SMARAN-ELECTRICAL-PRIVATE-LIMITED/U31900MH2014PTC255346

I am trying to search for the text "/director/*" in the HTML and then retrieve the Director name and post it to Excel:
 [GANGARAM SHREEPAT PATIL](https://www.zaubacorp.com/director/GANGARAM-SHREEPAT-PATIL/06760571)

Here is my code:

```
Set H3 = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("a")

     For Each Line In H3
        If Line.innerText Like "*/director/*" Then
            temp = Line.innerText
            Sheet2.Range("C" & x).Value = temp
         End If
     Next
```

Comment: @RyanWildry - Looking at the actual HTML on the linked page, I believe the OP needs to look for `/director/` in the `.href`, not the `.innerText`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mixing up the `.href` and `.innerText` properties of the anchor elements.

```
 For Each Line In H3
    If cbool(instr(1, Line.href, "/director/", vbtextcompare)) Then
        Sheet2.Range("C" & x).Value = Line.innerText
        x = x + 1
     End If
 Next
```

Comment: You don't need cBool. inStr will return as if it were true if the position is >0.

Comment: Yes, the CBool turns 0 and >0 into False and True.

Comment: It's not needed. Try it without.

Comment: I could have used `If instr(1, Line.href, "/director/", vbtextcompare) > 0 then` but I decided to do it this way.

Comment: You don't need >0 either.

Comment: That's just plain bad coding practice. A True in VBA is -1, not 1 so at a minimum you should be making a criteria comparison vs. greater-than-zero. The CBool conversion makes the conversion explicit.

Comment: For Each Line In H3
            If InStr(1, Line.href, "/director/", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    Sheet2.Range("C" & x).Value = Line.innertext
     Endif
Next

-------- This worked fine and retrieved the director name, but it picked up the second name, meaning there were 2 <a href> tags with "/director/" and this code picked up the second value. Can you please help me out why?

Comment: If you only want the first one then put an `exit for` after the .InnerText assignment instead of the `x = x + 1`.